# Timestamps based on hardware timer with overflow counter

Tags: timer, embedded, interrupt, msp430

I want to implement a timestamp functionality for my msp430-based platform.

My aim is to use a hardware timer, and count the number of times it overflows, to generate a long timestamp value (typically an uint32 for overflow counter, combined with the uint16 value of the hardware timer).

This is what I have:

- The overflow counter is incremented on interrupt,
- its value is checked every time a timestamp is requested (this is protected by interrupt locks).
- the overflow counter value is combined with the current hardware timer value to a large timestamp.

I run into problems when I take into consideration the timing of interrupts.

---

The first naive implementation I had:

```
uint16_t timer_value = timer_value_get();

__istate_t istate = interrupt_disable();
uint64_t overflow_count_local = overflow_count; // the volatile incremented on interrupt
interrupt_restore(istate);

return (overflow_count_local << 16u) + timer_value;
```

This is going to fail when an overflow occurs after getting the timer value, but before the interrupts are disabled. `overflow_count_local` would then be 1 greater than what it was upon assigning `timer_value`.

---

I have tried to add other checks to detect this possible interrupt

```
uint16_t timer_value = timer_value_get();

__istate_t istate = interrupt_disable();
uint16_t second_timer_value = timer_value_get();

uint64_t overflow_count_local = overflow_count; // the volatile incremented on interrupt
interrupt_restore(istate);

if (second_timer_value < timer_value) {
    // A HW timer overflow occured just before disabling interrupts.
    overflow_count_local--;
}

return (overflow_count_local << 16u) + timer_value;
```

This is not either going to work, this time because the timer might have overflown after disabling the interrupts, but before assigning `second_timer_value`. This would then make `overflow_count_local` one too little.

---

However I try to turn this around, there seems to always be a case which is not covered. Is there a known way to make this work?

Some limitations:

- The timer is used for other functionality as well (with capture/compare) and may not be stopped.
- The msp430's RTC module may not be used to that effect, because it is used to keep the actual time of the day.
- No 32 bit timer is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following algorithm is lock free (no interrupt disable required):

Get overflow then timer (in that order) until overflow is the same either side of the timer read.

```
uint32_t hi ;
uint16_t lo ;
do
{
    hi = overflow_count ;
    lo = timer_value_get() ;

} while( hi != overflow_count )

return (hi << 16 ) | lo ;
```

This should normally take zero or one iteration at most, unless there is an exceptionally long context switch to another thread or interrupt during which the timer overflowed again.

Comment: Nice. Since the ordering of the two rows in the loop's body matters, I guess it would be appropriate to make `hi` and `lo` `volatile`s? `overflow_count` is already volatile so it's not needed there, but for `lo`...

Comment: @Gauthier: It can't hurt.

Comment: Just a warning that this will only work correctly **_if interrupts are enabled_** (or, more specifically, if this code is interruptible by the timer IRQ). Often, MSP430 (or any microcontroller) code is interrupt driven, and if this is called from within an interrupt handler, where the MSP430 globally disables interrupts, then you will have the same race conditions as in the OP's examples (hardware overflow occurs during taking of time-stamp, but IRQ cannot be called to increment overflow_count because interrupts are disabled).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.  I don't see a need to disable interrupts with this.

```
timer_value_1 = timer_value_get();
overflow_count_snapshot = overflow_count;
timer_value_2 = timer_value_get();
if (timer_value_2 < timer_value_1)
{
    return (timer_value_2 + (overflow_count << 16)); // not the snapshot
}
else
{
    return (timer_value_2 + (overflow_count_snapshot << 16)); // you could use timer_value_1 or 2
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I am not sure that the assignment is atomic, especially since `overflow_count` is 32 bits. If the assignment is not atomic, and the interrupt occurs in the middle of it, the result could get ugly.

Comment: If timer_value_2 < timer_value_1 then you should ignore the snapshot.  But it's likely the interrupt has just occurred so it should be safe to read overflow_count again (i.e., it's not going to change again for some time).  I guess you could read overflow_count twice to be sure.  If timer_value_2 > timer_value_1 then there has not been an interrupt and overflow_count_snapshot is good.

Comment: I see. `overflow_count_snapshot` may be nonsense, but if it is then it is not used anyway. Interesting.